# How to pass php variables to a modal bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a laravel project where I have a recursion in which for every elements I want to create different html element. When I click to these links I want to open the modal by passing the right variable based on the element I clicked on.

EDIT: edited anteprima.blade.php:

```
<div class="rounded py-3 col-md-3 my-2 border mr-4">
<h5 class="font-weight-bold ellipsis"><i class="fas fas fa-list-ul mr-2"></i>{{ $playlist->nome }}</h5>

<small class="text-muted">Creata: {{ $playlist->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</small>

<div class="row px-3">
    <div>
        <button class="btn-sm btn-light border mr-2 open-modal my-2">Rinomina</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('playlists.destroy', $playlist) }}">
            @csrf
            @method('delete')
            <button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-secondary border my-2">Cancella</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function () {
        var myvariable = $(this).data('myvariable');
        $('#rename_playlist').modal('show', myvariable);
        console.log(myvariable);

    });
});
</script>
```

With the code I have now the modal take always the last $playlist but I want to have for every link a different $playlist.

EDIT: the edited index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn btn-warning rounded py-3 col-md-3 my-2 border mr-4" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#create_playlist'>
            <h5 class="font-weight-bold ellipsis"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-plus-square mr-2"></i>Nuova Playlist</a></h5>
        </div>
@foreach ($playlists as $playlist)
    @include('anteprima')
@endforeach
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="rename_playlist" data-myvariable='{{ json_encode($playlist) }}' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('playlists.update', $playlist) }}">
                @csrf
                @method('patch')
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title font-weight-bold" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Rinomina {{ $playlist->nome }}</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" value="{{ old('nome') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome della playlist" required />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancella</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Rinomina</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

UPDATE: I solved it using an id for every modal inside of the recursion.

Comment: Where is the modal? Can you show us that code so we can understand what the modal is trying to display?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can send extra data to the modal by appending to `data` attribute like so:

```
<div class="btn btn-warning rounded py-3 col-md-3 my-2 border mr-4" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#create_playlist' data-myvariable="your_data_here">
{{content}}
<div>
```

Then in JS, you can do:

```
var myvariable = $(this).data('myvariable');
```

Comment: Sorry, but how do I use your solution with the variable $playlist?

Comment: try `data-playlist='{{ json_encode($playlist) }}'` and JS would be the same

Comment: I tried with: var playlist = $(this).data('$playlist');
and data-playlist='{{ json_encode($playlist) }}'
but it doesn't work, it gives me the same result as before

Comment: @FridRic, dont json_encode in JS. json_encode in blade like so: `<div class="btn btn-warning rounded py-3 col-md-3 my-2 border mr-4" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#create_playlist' data-myvariable='{{ json_encode($playlist) }}'>
{{content}}
<div>` and then in JS you get it like before `var myvariable = $(this).data('myvariable');`

Comment: could you post what you get in console.log(myvariable) in JS here?

Comment: I got undefined

Comment: post your blade code where you send the data and your JS code of how you receive the data.

Comment: I edited the question with the edited file containing your code

Comment: Don't put `var myvariable = $(this).data('myvariable');` in document.ready. put it in `$(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function () {}`

Comment: I edited the question. I've changed the code but the result is the same: The modal takes the last $playlist and console.log(myvariable) gives me undefined

Comment: I think you need to move your modal inside your loop? It won't get individual `$playlist` object outside the loop. try it and let me know if it won't work.

Comment: I've tried it but now it takes just the first $playlist, before the last one.

Comment: can you try this in your JS `$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function (e) {
  var myvariable = $(e.target).data('myvariable');
}` while keeping your modal in a loop.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. I've also tried to put just var myvariable = $(e.target).data('myvariable'); but I got the same result as always